# Can a C# console app be registered in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a console application that is currently being hosted in Azure in a worker role.  I'm wanting to call some of the newer Microsoft API's that require you to have your application registered in Azure AD in order to get an application id to be used to get an OAuth token for the API.

As far as I know you can register Web Apps, Web Api's and native client apps in Azure AD.

Is it possible to register a console app in Azure AD?  If not do worker roles have an application id?  I have not seen where they do.

Comment: Can't you use Azure Web Jobs, which is based on WebApp? It would not make your life easier?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can register your app. A console app without a user authenticating is known as a daemon application. Here are the guidelines for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api.

You can simply register the console app either as a Web App or native app (it doesn't really matter if there is no user interaction), and then give it some App-Only permissions so it can make the calls with the Client Credentials Grant Flow, using only its client id and client secret.

*You should register it as a native application if you have a user signing in to it when it runs though. A console app is a native client app after all.* And then you could be using delegated permissions instead of app permissions.